# How to get data from Microsoft Word Forms into Excel automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up an excel spreadsheet with a vba coding that will transfer data from a microsoft word form.  I followed a tutorial on how to create this vba code but when i run it a run Error 438 appears: saying object doesn't support this property of method.  When i press debug it highlights "ActiveSheet.Cell.Clear" part of the code set up.  I have ensured that in the references that Microsoft Word 16 object is ticked.

I am new to vba coding so not an expert and struggling to find a solution

I tried removing that particular coding but then it start to highlight other codes.  I redid the code from scratch and for one moment it did take over the data from the form to excel but then stopped working again.

Comment: You should show your code in the question but it should be:
ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
the s is missing in your code

Comment: Also you should avoid use of ActiveSheet - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019981/how-to-avoid-using-select-activate-activesheet-activecell-in-my-specific-vba

Comment: Should be `Cells` not `Cell`.

Comment: Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, i added the s to cells and it worked.  But now i have a different issue.   I have had to move the  excel spreadsheet and forms to a sharepoint site for others in the team to access and for a back up when i am not about. Orignal path was on my C drive.   I went and changed the myfolder pathway in the code and it is now not taking any info from the forms to the excel spreadsheet.  Any suggestions. Will send part of the code in the next comment

Comment: Sub getWordFormData()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim CCtl As Word.ContentControl
Dim myfolder As String, strFile As String
Dim myWkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long

myfolder = "highlandcouncil1.sharepoint.com/sites/WFWP/Shared Documents/Evaluation & Self Assessment/Highland Toolkit/Self assessment/E-FORM/Toolkit Responses"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If myfolder = "" Then Exit Sub
Set myWkSht = ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear